# How to get the number of rows in ROWTYPE variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables Table1 an dTable2 that have identical columns. I need to check if a particular id is in one of them and return the row of data from whichever table.
I have the following PL/SQL code:

```
v_result Table1%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN

     SELECT a.*
     INTO   v_result
     FROM   Table1 a
     WHERE  a.id    = 123;


  EXCEPTION

     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- when record not found

        SELECT b.*
        INTO   v_result
        FROM   Table2 b
        WHERE  b.id    = 123;

  END;
```

The issue is that the exception does not get thrown, so v_result returns no data. How can I check v_result for the number of rows?

For cursor I can use ROWCOUNT but v_result is not a cursor.

I also tried using count property but it errored out.

I changed my code to:

```
v_result Table1%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN

     SELECT a.*
     INTO   v_result
     FROM   Table1 a
     WHERE  a.id    = 123;

     if v_result.count =0 then
        SELECT b.*
        INTO   v_result
        FROM   Table2 b
        WHERE  b.id    = 123;
     end if;

  EXCEPTION

     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  -- when record not found

        SELECT b.*
        INTO   v_result
        FROM   Table2 b
        WHERE  b.id    = 123;

  END;
```

And got an error `component 'count' must be declared`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can only store a single row such a variable.

Comment: so how can I figure out if nothing gets returned if no exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You may use only a single row in a record variable. If you want to store and count multiple rows, you may define a collection of records and use `BULK COLLECT INTO` to load all of them at once and it won't raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND`. The `count` function works on collections.

```
DECLARE
TYPE type_tab1 IS TABLE OF  Table1%ROWTYPE; 
TYPE type_tab2 IS TABLE OF  Table2%ROWTYPE; 

v_result1 type_tab1;
v_result2 type_tab2;
BEGIN

     SELECT a.*
       BULK COLLECT INTO  v_result1
     FROM   Table1 a
     WHERE  a.id = 123;

     if v_result1.count = 0 then
        SELECT b.* BULK COLLECT
          INTO   v_result2
        FROM   Table2 b
        WHERE  b.id    = 123;
     end if;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_result1 ='|| v_result1.count);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_result2 ='|| v_result2.count);


 END;
  /
```

Output for the [**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e51b41f128ce2857f7b1b93013762d9a)

```
v_result1 =0
v_result2 =1
```

If your intention is to simply check if a row exists, then a simpler and efficient approach would be to use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN 
          EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
                 FROM table1
               WHERE id = 123
          ) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 
      END
INTO v_count
FROM dual;

IF v_count = 0
    THEN
     ..
     ..
```

Comment: if I use my original code, how can I figure out that the row getting returned is empty?

Comment: @CodingDuchess : That's what this answer is about. Which part have you not understood?  `if v_result1.count = 0 then` is doing just that

Comment: I am not planning on changing the original query. And in that case v_result.count gave me an error

Comment: @CodingDuchess : Nothing has been changed in the original query, it's just that you can't store multiple rows in a record variable, due to which I used a collection to store the  loaded data using `BULK COLLECT` . Do you mean you can't change the code at all? Then there's very little we could do to help you.